# Assign integer values with a certain sum based on column values

Tags: r, math, integer

I am assigning traps to locations with certain establishment risks for pests. I have calculated the risk of establishment per site.
I would like to find an efficient and safe method to assign a certain number of traps to the sites (for example 10 sites in total). This means I have to multiply the risk values with a certain value until the sum of all integers is the value I am looking for (10, for example).

Is there a way to do this in R?

Example:

```
example <- NULL
example$site <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")
example$est_risk <- c(0.001,0.05,0.07,0.1)
example <- as.data.frame(example)
```

gives

[image]

and I am looking for a convenient way to get

[image]

I have many more sites, and will also need to do it for various pests, so doing it manually is cumbersome and error-prone.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is the risk affecting the number of traps in a certain way or simply the riskier the more traps needed? Also is there a threshold for no traps? as in site `a`?

Comment: What happens if no solution exists. Say the risk was all .25 and you wanted a total of 11. How do you decide who get the extra 1?

Comment: @ Sotos: I have a certain number of traps I can assign, and I assign these traps according to establishment risk

Comment: @Sotos I think it's trying to find a value `x` such that `sum(round(example$est_risk*x))==10` where `x` in this case can be 46-48.

Comment: @MrFlick: I do not know, but the likelihood of that happening gets quite low with 143 sites with values that range from 0.000095200 to 0.006347191 - I hope.

Comment: Could you perhaps calculate the expected number traps at each site by risk using `example$expected_traps <- 10 * (example$est_risk / (sum(example$est_risk)))` then determine how many traps using some other mechanism (i.e., as a lazy way: `round(example$expected_traps)`, which gives `[1] 0 2 3 5`)?

Comment: @jpsmith: this works with this example, but when we have many more sites they all get assigned '0' when we round.

Comment: Oh yea I figured it wouldn’t be perfect – that’s why it’s a comment and not an answer – just trying to help you think through! Great question though. Do all sites need at least one trap?

Comment: @jpsmith thanks! I have many more sites than traps, so not every site gets a trap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution starts with 0 traps assigned, then adds them to sites one at a time such that after each addition the Euclidean distance between distribution of the traps and the distribution of the risk is minimised.

```
trapsDistribtion <- function(risk, N){
x <- rep(0,length(risk))
for(i in 1:N){
j = which.min(sapply(seq_along(risk), \(i) {
  y = x
  y[i] = y[i]+1
  sum(((risk/sum(risk)) - (y/sum(y)))^2)
  }))
x[j] <- x[j]+1
}
 
x
}



> trapsDistribtion(c(0.001,0.05,0.07,0.1),10)
[1] 0 2 3 5
```